Failed to Restore Data from Public Storage After Android app reinstallation
I'm developing an Android app that uses MediaStore to save a JSON file with app-specific duration data. I've implemented a mechanism to save data to public storage and attempt to restore it after app reinstallation, but the restoration is not working consistently.
Current Behavior:

When the app is first installed and runs, it saves a JSON file to MediaStore Downloads
After uninstalling and reinstalling the app, the app fails to retrieve the previously saved file
Instead of restoring the existing data, the app seems to be creating a new file or entry

Relevant Code Snippet:
I have a restoreTrailsDurationAfterReinstall() method in my repository that attempts to:

Check for local database entry
If no local entry, search for a saved file in public storage using TrailsDurationPublicStorageManager.findSavedFileUri()
If file is found, read and restore the data

Sample Code:
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
fun restoreTrailsDurationAfterReinstall(): ResponseWrapper<TrailsDurationResponse> {
    return safeDatabaseCall {
        // Existing local database check
        val localTrailsDuration = database.trailsDurationDao.getTrailsDuration()
        if (localTrailsDuration != null) {
            // Return local data if exists
        }

        // Search for file in public storage
        val savedFileUri = TrailsDurationPublicStorageManager.findSavedFileUri(context)
        savedFileUri?.let { uri ->
            val restoredEntity = TrailsDurationPublicStorageManager.getTrailsDurationData(context, uri)
            // Restore logic...
        }
        // Fallback logic...
    }
}

Questions:
Why might the saved file not be found after app reinstallation?
Are there any best practices for ensuring data persistence across app reinstalls?
Could permissions or storage access be causing this issue?
What I Tried:

Implemented a public storage save mechanism using MediaStore's Downloads provider
Created a method findSavedFileUri() to locate the previously saved JSON file
Added a restoration method restoreTrailsDurationAfterReinstall() to:

First check for local database entries
If no local entry exists, search for a file in public storage
Attempt to read and restore data from the found file


Added comprehensive logging to track the file search and retrieval process

What I Expected:

When the app is reinstalled, it should successfully find and restore the JSON file saved during the previous app installation
The restored data should include all previous app state, specifically:

Attendance status
Clock-in date
Expiration date
Limit of resume button clicks



Actual Result:

The app fails to find or read the previously saved file
Instead of restoring existing data, the app either:

Creates a new file/entry
Returns a "No data found" response
Potentially loses previously saved app state



